# How to convert an array to an object in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have:

```
{
     dis:{["String1","String2","String3"]},
     par:"pony"
}
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
[
    { name: 'String1', value: "pony" },
    { name: 'String2', value: "pony" },
    { name: 'String3', value: "pony" }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change to valid js data you can do this with [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var obj = {
  dis: ["String1", "String2", "String3"],
  par: "pony"
}

var result = obj.dis.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r.push({name: e, value: obj.par});
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily, but beware you have double parentheses (mustaches and square bracket).

```
var 
    data = {
        dis: ["String1","String2","String3"],
        par: "pony"
    }, 

  result = [];

for (var index in data.dis)
    result.push({ name: data.dis[index], value: data.par}
```

you can find the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tztur5cc/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Array.protoype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var obj = {
     dis:["String1","String2","String3"],
     par:"pony"
};

var arrOfObj = obj.dis.map(function(name) {
    return {
        name: name,
        value: obj.par
    }
});

console.log(arrOfObj)
```

Or lodash's [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map):

```js
var obj = {
     dis:["String1","String2","String3"],
     par:"pony"
};

var arrOfObj = _.map(obj.dis, function(name) {
    return {
        name: name,
        value: obj.par
    }
});

console.log(arrOfObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```